# Celery works but celeryd doesn't

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to get Django and Celery functioning in production. My Django project is laid out like so:

```
- project_root
  - manage.py
  - app1
    - settings.py
    - celery_config.py
    - __init__.py, models.py, etc...
  - app2
    - tasks.py
    - __init__.py, models.py, etc...
  - app3
    - tasks.py
    - __init__.py, models.py, etc...
```

and so on...

Now, during development, I can run `celery -A app1 worker -l info` in the project_root. This autodetects tasks in the other apps and generally runs fine.

For production, I obviously need to run `celery` as a daemon. I've followed the `celeryd` instructions at [the celery website](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#example-django-configuration).

When I run a task (either from `python manage.py shell` or from the running Django app), I get:

```
>>> from app2.tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(1,1)
>>> result.ready()
False
>>> result.get(timeout=1)
TimeoutError
... traceback
```

`add()` is just a simple function for testing purposes:

```
@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

In the celery logs, I get:

```
[2014-11-08 12:43:59,191: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2014-11-08 12:43:59,196: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2014-11-08 12:44:00,205: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2014-11-08 12:44:00,228: WARNING/MainProcess] w1@ubuntu ready.
[2014-11-08 12:44:09,216: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'app2.tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

{'utc': True, 'chord': None, 'args': (1, 2), 'retries': 0, 'expires': None, 'task': 'app2.tasks.add', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'timelimit': (None, None), 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': None, 'id': '82e59cbf-88be-4542-82a7-452f2fbafe95'} (213b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 455, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: 'app2.tasks.add'
```

Here is my `/etc/default/celeryd` for reference:

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/var/django/project_root"
CELERYD_OPTS="--concurrency=1"
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="app1.celery_config"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="amqp"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

And my `project_root/app1/celery_config.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app1.settings')
app = Celery('app1', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
        print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

How can I get Celery working correctly as a daemon?

Comment: Are you missing an underscore in the task decorator?

Comment: Typo in post. Fixed now.

Comment: Is app2 in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes. The bizarre thing is that `celery` works on the command line but not as a daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be adding

```
CELERY_APP="app1"
CELERY_NODES="app1"
```

to `/etc/default/celeryd`

Answer (score 4):

Your celery instance/app has naming problems.

### **Solution:**

Since

```
celery -A app1 worker -l info
```

is working, if you add

```
CELERY_APP_ARG="app1"
```

to your `celeryd` file, everything should work fine.

**Note:**

Using celeryd is painful. Also it is deprecated now. So you can use

**1. celery multi:**

You can start same worker in your project root without any bash scripts like this

```
celery multi start my_awesome_worker -A app1 \
--pidfile="somewhere/celery/%n.pid" \
--logfile="somewhere/celery/%n.log"
```

One more advantage of this method is, you can start daemon without sudo privileges.

**2. Supervisor:**

If you are already using supervisor, you can start one more process for celery which makes managing multiple workers super easy.

### **Explanation:**

When you run worker from your terminal with

```
celery -A app1 worker -l info
```

in your log somewhere, it shows a list of tasks which it will process, something like this

```
[tasks]
  . app1.tasks.add
```

Now if you do

```
In [1]: from app1.tasks import add

In [2]: add.name
Out[2]: 'app1.tasks.name'      #attention please

In [3]: result = add.delay(1,1)

In [4]: result.ready()
Out[4]: True

In [5]: result.get(timeout=1)
Out[5]: 2
```

Everything works fine because, the registered task name and the name of task you run are same. On the other hand if you do

```
In [1]: from app1 import tasks

In [2]: tasks.add.name
Out[2]: 'tasks.name'     #attention please

In [3]: result = add.delay(1,1)

In [4]: result.ready()
Out[4]: False

In [5]: result.get(timeout=1)
Out[5]: TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-10-ade09ca12a13> in <module>()
        ----> 1 r.get(timeout=1)
```

It throws error because the registered task name is `app1.tasks.add` and the task you queued is `tasks.add`. So your worker has no idea about the task you added. More about this [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports).

**Warining:**

Also if you are running a celery for another app lets say `foo`

```
celery worker -l info -A foo
```

which has registered task `bar`

```
[tasks]
  . foo.tasks.bar
```

Now if you queue your old `app1.tasks.add`, this worker will throw key error. So you have to import & route tasks correctly.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 455, in on_task_received
KeyError: 'app1.tasks.add'
```

Because it has no idea about the task you have queued. You have to import & [route tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) correctly.